# Line drawing doesn't work in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios8, uigraphicscontext

I'm drawing a horizontal line in a custom `UITableViewCell`.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var columns: [CGFloat] = []

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.60)
        for column in columns {
            // Drawing the vertical line
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, column, 10)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, column, self.bounds.size.height - 10)
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }

    func addColumn(position: CGFloat) {
        columns.append(position)
    }
}
```

From the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I specify the x position value for the line.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        cell.addColumn(40)

        return cell
}
```

This solution works fine in iOS 8. But I have to support iOS 7 as well. Strangely the line doesn't appear when I run the app in iOS 7.

I can't find any answer regarding this. Anyone got an idea why this is and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think drawing on UITableViewCell is a good idea. Note that contentView is the top most view in the cell, there may be some view blur the background of UITableViewCell, so you can add a `UIView` with 1.0 width on it or draw on the contentView.

Comment: What happens if you call 'cell.setNeedsDisplay() after adding columns

Comment: @rakeshbs You mean in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method after this line `cell.addColumn(40)`?

Comment: Yes. Or inside addcolumn in your custom cell.

Comment: @rakeshbs Tried both ways. No change.